# What stats do different damage types scale off of?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have seen lots of controversy about this when it comes to fire (pyromancy) saying it is Int **AND** Fai and other say it is higher of Int **OR** Fai.

I am assuming that spells like dark and fire are based off the same stats as added fire or dark weapon damage.

Here is what I think and would like to verify:

```
Normal: STR or DEX depending on weapon
Fire: ??? INT AND FAI or higher of INT OR FAI 
Lightning: FAI
Magic: Int
Dark: ??? Lower of INT or FAI stats
Poison: DEX?
Bleed: DEX?
Mundane: character's lowest stat
```

I dont know if players can use these types:

```
Curse: ?
Petrify: ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some wiki research and I think I have it figured out:

```
Normal: STR and/or DEX depending on weapon
Fire: INT and FAI equally 
Lightning: FAI
Magic: INT
Dark: Lower of INT or FAI
Poison: Slight DEX 
Bleed: Slight DEX 
Mundane: Lowest stat 
Raw: removes scaling but adds high base damage
```

Sources: 
[dark](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Hexes), [fire](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Pyromancies), [Other](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Upgrades#Ore)